# unable to findright file path

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am facing some problem to fix the right file path.

I have a configuration file and following is the entry in config.properties:

```
strMasterTestSuiteFilePath="D:\\KeywordDrivenFramework\\MasterTestSuiteFile.xls"
```

Then i tried to read this property as

```
Properties prop=new Properties();
prop.load("config.properties")
String strpath=prop.getProperty("strMasterTestSuiteFilePath")
Syso(strpath)  //prints above path with single slash as D:\KeywordDrivenFramework\MasterTestSuiteFile.xls
//When i use the same var for File existance check it say not exists
File obj=new File(strpath)
if(obj.exists())
 Syso("Exists....")
else
 Syso("Does not exist....")
```

Why it is going to else block, even though the file exists at path?
How to overcome it?
I tried
`String str= strpath.replaceAll("\","\\")`  //but i am getting some syntax error "The method replaceAll(String, String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String)"
Can anyone help me how to overcome this?

Find the code which i am trying, where i am going wrong?

```
public void LoadMasterTestSuite()
    {
        String strGlobalConfigSettingFilePath=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/GlobalConfigurationSettings.properties";
        FileInputStream objFIS; //Variable to hold FileSystem Objet
        File objFile;           //Variable to hold File Object

        try 
        {
            objFIS = new FileInputStream(new File(strGlobalConfigSettingFilePath));
            globalObjProp.load(objFIS);
            strMasterTSFilePath=globalObjProp.getProperty("strMasterTestSuiteFilePath");
            objAppLog.info("Master Test Suite File Path configured as "+strMasterTSFilePath);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            objAppLog.info("Unable to find Global Configuration Settings File. So aborting...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String str=strMasterTSFilePath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        objFile=new File(str);
        System.out.println(str);
        if(objFile.exists())
        {
            LoadTestSuite(strMasterTSFilePath);
        }
        else
        {
            objAppLog.info("Master Test Suite File not found at Path: "+strMasterTSFilePath);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `String str= strpath.replaceAll("\","\\")` won't work since you have to be able to create the `String` with backslash (you are not) at first place and then replace them. And a silly question but does the file actually exists?

Comment: Might be, you're using incorrect extension of your file. Can you please check if your file's - `MasterTestSuiteFile` extension is really `xls`? It could be `xlsx` or something else.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you wanted to do was:

`String str= strpath.replaceAll("\\\\","\\")`

`\` is a special character in a String. To Treat it like a normal character, put another `\` in front of it, so `'\'` actually is `'\\'`.

And for your case, I think you want to use `.replace()` and not `.replaceAll()`.

Comment: String str= strpath.replaceAll("\\","\\\\") //when i try this statement i am getting PatternSyntaxException

Comment: this is because `.replaceAll` requires a regex as first argument. try using `.replace` instead ;)

Comment: I tried String str=strMasterTSFilePath.replace('\', '\\'); It says Invalid Character constant.

Comment: you should try `String str= strpath.replace("\\","\\\\")`

Comment: do not use replaceAll(), use replace()!

Comment: with replace, now it got file name with "\\", but still fileobj.exists() return false. Can you please look at my code, which i updated?

Comment: use this and you are fine: `String str= strpath.replace("\\\\","\\")`

Comment: No luck ZerO, String str=strMasterTSFilePath.replace("\\\\", "\\");
  objFile=new File(str);
  System.out.println(str);
  if(objFile.exists())
  {
   LoadTestSuite(strMasterTSFilePath);
  }
  else
  {
   objAppLog.info("Master Test Suite File not found at Path: "+strMasterTSFilePath);
   System.exit(-1);
  } Still going to else block

Comment: the worst part i see here, if the variable holds the value str=""D:\\KeywordDrivenFramework\\MasterTestSuiteFile.xls" then it is going to else block. but if i put directly the file path like File objFile=new File("D:\\KeywordDrivenFramework\\MasterTestSuiteFile.xls"); It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you debug, is strpath getting the correct path from the config file? I would also make sure that you're referencing the correct file path (paste the location into Windows Explorer and see if the file exists). If D:\ is a shared drive, use the actual server location.

Also, you can make sure that the extension of the Excel workbook is .xls and not .xlsx.

Comment: The file exists, the only problem is when i read prop.getProperty(Sting) it returns with single "\". With this path if i create a file object and check using exists() method it is not able to fine.